# How can I use cascaded namespaces in moc files?

Tags: c++, qt, moc

I'm currently writing a small application with Qt (4.7). And I use nested namespaces like

```
namespace app {
    namespace core {
        class CoreClass {...}
    }
}
```

Because I'm a litte bit lazy, I am using symbols for shortcuts that hold the opening and closing namespace declarations:

```
APP_START
    class CoreClass {...}
APP_END
```

The symbols are defined in a global header file.

So far, so good. It works perfect on compile time. But when the moc generator creates the moc files, it missed the namespace declarations and the methods are generated in the standard namespace. When don't use the symbols, everything works fine.

When I redefine the `QT_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE` symbol, the compiler throws a redefine-warning on every include. This works indeed, but I think it's not really nice.

Is there a better solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First I'd find out why moc isn't doing the macro substitution. Maybe -I is wrong?

Second, you can try the -D parameter to moc. Maybe something like: moc "-DAPP_BEGIN=namespace app { namespace core {"

Comment: I don't think that's it, because I'm using Qt Creator. Your approach of finding out why moc dosn't do the subsitution sounds good to me. I'm following that one.

Comment: I was playing a little bit with the moc generator from the Qt tools. And it seems that there is no way to tell it to parse the preprocessor directives. Sad.